# Darcy's law using Hubbert potential vs pseudo-pressure for a gas

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, porous-media

How does one show the equivalence (or difference) of Darcy's law written using Hubbert's potential of a real gas to that of Darcy's law written using the concept of pseudo-pressure (aka pseudo-potential)?

---

To further describe my question and my efforts so far, here are my explanations and sticking points:

If we take [Hubbert's potential](https://www.google.com/search?q=hubbert%20potential&oq=hubbert%20potent&gs_l=serp.3.1.0i10k1j0i22i30k1l2.356681.361142.0.365285.14.14.0.0.0.0.422.1811.0j5j1j1j1.8.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..6.8.1797...0.tbILjx33rUM) to be defined as
$$\tag{1} \Phi^h=gz+\int_{p_b}^p \frac{dp}{\rho}$$

with the elevation coordinate ($z$) taken as positive upward,

then [Darcy's law](https://www.google.com/search?q=darcy%27s%20law&oq=darcy&gs_l=serp.3.0.0i67k1l2j0j0i131i10k1j0l6.47216.47926.0.49563.5.5.0.0.0.0.163.583.0j4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.4.578...0i131k1.LlFqPeFdPNE) can be written as
$$\tag{2} q=-\frac{kA\rho}{\mu} \frac{d\Phi^h}{ds}$$

where $s$ is the distance in the direction of flow, which is taken as positive.

Invoking Eqn 1 in Eqn 2, and distributing the density ($\rho$) term, we get,
$$\tag{3} q=-\frac{kA}{\mu} \frac{d(\rho gz+\int_{p_b}^p dp)}{ds}$$

To obtain Eqn 3 in difference form, noting that dynamic viscosity ($\mu$) is a function of pressure, we separate variables and integrate from distance $0$ to $L$, where the pressures are $p_1$ and $p_2$, respectively
$$\tag{4} q \int_{0}^L ds=-kA \int_{p_1}^{p_2} \frac{1}{\mu} d\left(\rho gz+\int_{p_b}^p dp\right)$$

I should state that the relationship between pressure ($p$) and gas density is

$$\tag{5} \rho=\frac{pM_w}{z_gRT}$$

If we take the gas molecular weight ($M_w$), universal gas constant ($R$), and temperature ($T$) as constants, then we can simplify the expression as

$$\tag{6} \rho=\frac{p}{z_g}$$

Also, another aspect of gas flow I should mention is that as the gas flows from high potential to low potential it expands, i.e. the volumetric rate ($q$) is not constant.  However, the mass rate ($\dot m$) is a constant, and the relationship between mass rate and volumetric rate is
$$\tag{7} q=\frac{\dot m}{\rho}$$

Continuing from Eqn 4, I think I can further separate variables as so:
$$\tag{8} q\int_0^L ds=-kA\left[\int_{p_1}^{p_2}\frac{\rho g}{\mu} dz+\int_{p_1}^{p_2} \int_{p_b}^{p}\frac{dp}{\mu}\right]$$

Substituting the relationship between mass rate and volumetric rate (Eqn 7) and then multiplying through by density,
$$\tag{9} \dot m \int_0^L ds=-kA\left[\int_{p_1}^{p_2}\frac{\rho^2 g}{\mu} dz+\int_{p_1}^{p_2} \int_{p_b}^{p}\frac{\rho}{\mu} dp\right]$$

I will note here that the generalize form for [pseudo-pressure](https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=pseudopressure&oq=pseudopressure&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i10k1l5j0i10i30k1j0i5i30k1.1112.5352.0.5511.17.14.1.2.2.0.171.1471.4j9.13.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..1.15.1360.0..0i131k1j0i131i46k1j46i131k1.6W_C-r5tSPU) (denoted as $m(p)$) is written as
$$\tag{10} m(p)=\int_{p_b}^p \frac{\rho}{\mu}dp$$

therefore,

$$\tag{11} \dot m \int_0^L ds=-kA\left[\int_{p_1}^{p_2}\frac{\rho^2 g}{\mu} dz+\int_{p_1}^{p_2} m(p)\right]$$

At this point I'm not sure how to handle the integral of the first term on the right hand side of Eqn 11.  Performing the other integrals, I believe I am stuck here:

$$\tag{12} \dot m L=-kA\left[\int_{p_1}^{p_2}\frac{\rho^2 g}{\mu} dz+(m(p_2)-m(p_1))\right]$$

and then

$$\tag{13} \dot m L=-kA\left[\int_{p_1}^{p_2}\frac{\rho^2 g}{\mu} dz+\Delta m(p)\right]$$

Comment: I feel like I've seen this question posted previously.  Was it?

Comment: Yes & no, this question is focused on derivation, I do not know how to handle that integral in eqn 13 (or if I have got things correct to get to that integral)

Comment: @ChesterMiller in the other post, regarding the integral $\int_{p_1}^{p_2} \frac{\rho^2 g}{\mu} dz$, you said because the gravitational term is small, we can neglect the effect of pressure on density and viscosity in this term.  I am curious to 1) understand how to perform this integral; 2) to understand, maybe by example/further explanation, why we can neglect the effect of pressure on density and viscosity; 3) how to see that this term, the gravitational term, is small.

Comment: All you need to do is look up in the literature how to quantify these effects.  For the effect of pressure, for example, you would use the bulk compressibility.  Also, I'm sure that the effect of pressure on viscosity, even at the pressures at depth, are tiny.  I would be much more concerned with the affects of TDS and temperature on density and viscosity.

Comment: @ChesterMiller for the effect of pressure I would use bulk compressibility for the density variable? If yes, why wouldn't I substitute the $p/z$ relationship the real gas law gives us? Also, how can I perform this integration of effects of pressure when my differential is wrt location? I.e. $\int_p ( ) dz$ ?

Comment: Oops.  I got it in my head that you were dealing with a liquid.  I will provide an answer in a short while on how to deal with a gas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having so much trouble with the mathematics is that you are forcing yourself (for whatever reason) to work in terms of the Hubbert potential.  As a result, the mathematics are becoming unwieldy.  I'm going to work in terms of pressure.  Let's assume that the flow is vertical, and temporarily assume that the viscosity is constant so that we can concentrate at the pressure effect on density.  Let's also assume that the gas can be modelled as an ideal gas (so that the gas compressibility factor $z_g$ is equal to unity.  Then the differential equation for the pressure variation with elevation z is given by Darcy's law as:
$$\frac{dp}{dz}+\rho g=-\frac{\mu}{k\rho A}\dot{m}$$where $\dot{m}$ is the upward mass flow rate.  If we substitute the ideal gas law into this relationship, we get:$$\frac{dp}{dz}+\frac{Mg}{RT}p=-\frac{\mu \dot{m}RT}{kAM}\frac{1}{p}$$If we multiply both sides of this equation by p, we get:$$\frac{dp^2}{dz}+2\frac{Mg}{RT}p^2=-2\frac{\mu \dot{m}RT}{kAM}$$This is a first order linear ordinary differential equation for $p^2$ as a function of z.  Do you know how to solve it?

ADDENDUM:

If the boundary condition is $p=p_0$ at $z=z_0$, the solution for the pressure as a function of z is:

$$p^2=p_0^2-(p_0^2+p_c^2)\left[1-e^{-\frac{2Mg(z-z_0)}{RT}}\right]$$where the "characteristic pressure" $p_c$ is given by:$$p_c=\left(\frac{RT}{Mg}\right)\sqrt{\frac{\mu \dot{m} g}{kA}}$$

Comment: If the form of this eqn is $dy/dx+P(x)y=Q(x)$, then the $y=p^2$, $x=z$, and my integration factor, $I$, is $I=e^{\int p(x) dx}=e^{\int \frac{2Mg}{RT} dz}=e^(\frac{2Mgz}{RT})$?

Comment: If what I said above is correct, I found that after integrating I get:
$$e^(\frac{2Mgz}{RT})p^2=-\frac{\mu \dot m R^2 T^2}{kAM^2} e^(\frac{2Mgz}{RT})+C$$

Comment: Yes.  You're using the integrating factor apporach.

Comment: This is correct, except for a factor of g omitted from the denominator of the first term on the rhs.  Now, employ some sort of boundary condition.

Comment: would the simplest BC be that when $\Delta p =0; \dot m = 0$?

Comment: No.  It would be p equals some specified value at some z elevation. This has to correspond to some known pressure at some known elevation.

Comment: if at $z=L$ $p=0$ psig, then $C=\frac{\mu \dot m R^2 T^2}{kAM^2g}\cdot e^{\left(\frac{2MgL}{RT}\right)}$?

Comment: You can't use gauge pressure for compressible flow.  You must use absolute pressure.

Comment: OK, so if the units used was atmospheres, for simplicity here, we can say, at $z=L$; $p=1$ atm (absolute), then $C=e^{\left(\frac{2MgL}{RT}\right)} \left[1+\frac{\mu \dot m R^2 T^2}{kAM^2g}\right]$

Comment: If the above is correct, how can we put it all together to show the relative importance of the pressure head vs the elevation head?

Comment: See my ADDENDUM

Comment: The relative importance of the flow-driven pressure effect to the pressure effect resulting from elevation difference is captured by the dimensionless group $(p_c/p_0)^2$